# SVN errors in angular 2 project

Tags: angular, svn

When installing Angular, svn is not working in the project root folder:

`The error occur during commit file using svn is :The specified command svn-commit.tmp is invalid for available option, see 'ng help'`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should update @angular/cli. This command is available since 1.0.0-beta.32

just run this command in your terminal :

`sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`